# How to prevent JavaScript previous data

Tags: javascript

Hi guys i write a JavaScript code to get data with getJSON method by selecting an options.
but my problem is when i select new options the old data still exist on my checkboxs and new values added to old data !! how i can unchecke older checkboxs by selecting new options.

```
<select onchange="OnSelectionChange(this)">
    <option value="1">one</option>
    <option value="2">two</option>
    <option value="3">three</option>
    <option value="4">four</option>
</select>



<ul class="icheck-list">
{foreach $rps as $rp}
    <li>
        <input type="checkbox" name="updatePERM[]" value="{$rp.id}">
        <label for="minimal-checkbox-1-15">{$rp.rname}</label>
    </li>
{/foreach}
</ul>


<script type="text/javascript">
function OnSelectionChange (select) {
var selectedOption = select.options[select.selectedIndex];

var url = "./include/getPerms.php?key="+selectedOption.value+"";
$.getJSON(url, function(data) {
    $.each(data.rules, function(i, rule) {      
    $('input:checkbox[value="' + rule.id + '"]').attr('checked', true).iCheck({
        checkboxClass: 'icheckbox_flat-pink',
        });
    });
  });
}
</script>
```

Comment: I have 30 checkbox and when checkbox values = someDATA then they go on checked .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would want to reset the checkboxes before setting the new values:

```
$('input:checkbox').attr('checked', false)
```

Comment: nice but now i can just select every options for one time and with second times checkboxs not works

Comment: I'm not sure what you're saying.  It may be that you only want to call `iCheck` once instead of on every callback.